# How to submit values of a php form and a javascript pop up?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a PHP page which have some form information and at the end of the form i have a submit button. I know how to take all the user inputs from the form using the PHP post method. My problem is the following, how can i create a mini pop up form which will pop up after the user clicks the submit button. The pop up form will ask from the user if the submission of the information is urgent or not, the user will just choose between urgent or not urgent and click a button in the mini pop up form("proceed") that will close the pop up and send all information of the user inputs along with the pop up in a different PHP page. Can someone please guide with this problem?

The source code of my form at the moment is the following

```
 <?php include "includes/tasksheader.php"; ?>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="main1">
            <div class="contact-section">
            <div class="container">

                <form>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-line">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputUsername">Social Ensuarance Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Ensuarance Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail">Land Regisrty Department</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Land Registry">
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">Income Tax Office</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Tax Office">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">Court</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Court">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">Limassol District Administration</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="District Administration">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">Municipality</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Municipality">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputUsername">VAT Department</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="VAT">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail">RCB Bank</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="RCB Bank">
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">Hellenic Bank</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Hellenic Bank">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">Bank of Cyprus</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Bank of Cyprus">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">CDB Bank</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="CDB Bank">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">Other</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Other">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for ="description"> Message</label>
                            <textarea  class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter Your Message"></textarea>

                        <div>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Send Message</button>
                        </div>  
                        </div>                                              
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in regards

Comment: please provide code part of your page too....

Comment: what you have tried?please post your code

Comment: From a UX (User experience) point of view, creating a pop up for the user to select `urgent` or `not urgent` is an anti-design. Why not just add two radio buttons to the main form and move on.

Comment: name attribute missing in all input fields and all input fields have same ID....

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you'll need to do the following:
first create the popup form(having two buttons...) then you'll need to write the following in your javascript file:

```
$('form').on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('popup').fadeIn();
  ...
}
```

or

```
$('button').on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('popup').fadeIn();
  ...
}
```

then in your popup you'll again need to `preventDefault` and do whatever is on your intention.
I hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the button to a submit button and set an onsubmit for the form:

```
<button type="submit">

<form method="post" onsubmit="openPopup();return false">
```

And then use javascript to open the popup with all the data you need.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes but if i do that will i be able to submit the php values of the form as well?

Comment: What do you mean with php values?

If you mean the contents of the input fields in your form, then yes.

JS can read those out and transmit them to the popup. You can save them there in hidden input fields and then send all data from the popup.
Or you could also let the popup give its information (the "urgent-flag") back to the original page and then send it all from there.
Either way if you do it properly you can still send all the data contained in the form.